How to add Report-To custom response header to GCP BackendConfig
I have a BackendConfig with headers like such:
version: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: name
  namespace: ns
spec:
  customResponseHeaders:
    headers:
    - "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'self'; report-uri https://o250588.ingest.us.sentry.io/api/xxx/security/?sentry_key=yyy; report-to csp-endpoint"
    - "Report-To: {'group':'csp-endpoint', 'max_age':10886400, 'endpoints': [{'url':'https://o250588.ingest.us.sentry.io/api/zzz/security/?sentry_key=yyy'}], 'include_subdomains':true}"


When this BackendConfig is applied I see the following error in the gce_backend_service:

Invalid value for field 'resource.customResponseHeaders[1]': 'Report-To: {'group':'csp-endpoint', 'max_age':10886400, 'endpoints':[{'url':'https://o250588.ingest.us.sentry.io/api/zzz/security/?sentry_key=yyy'}], 'include_subdomains':true}'. Missing closing brace '}' in header field value.

The closing brace is not missing, it's at the end of the string. Maybe it should be escaped or so?
I've tried using multiline YAML and quoting the JSON in single quotes and the rest in doubles, but if the YAML is valid I get the same error about the "missing closing brace".
Examples of escaping:

- 'Report-To: {\"group\":\"csp-endpoint\", \"max_age\":10886400, \"endpoints\": [{\"url\":\"https://o250588.ingest.us.sentry.io/api/zzz/security/?sentry_key=yyy\"}], \"include_subdomains\":true}'

- > 
  Report-To: {'group':'csp-endpoint', 'max_age':10886400, 'endpoints': [{'url':'https://o250588.ingest.us.sentry.io/api/zzz/security/?sentry_key=yyy'}], 'include_subdomains':true}




How can I add the Report-To header with the JSON to a GCP BackendConfig?

Ensure that your GKE cluster is version 1.25 or later and try escaping the quotes within the JSON string

@SaiChandraGadde thanks for your suggestions. The GKE cluster is version 1.29.6. Setting other response headers does work. And I have tried escaping the quotes in various ways. For example with explicit escapes using \", using single quotes outside and double quotes inside and vice versa. Also the same variations with multiline strings. All attempts give the same error "missing closing brace". I will extend the answer with what escape variations I tried.
